Как сделать 2 div в одной строке? (React)
Мне нужно сделать чтобы два этих эллемента были в одну строку, а переносились только при изменения ширины экрана.

Первая это то, что в браузере у меня, а второе как должно выглядеть на примере шаблона в фигма

Оберните во flex контейнет(например). Для более точного ответа, приведите пример кода и финальной html разметки со стилями

.container {
   display: flex;
   //когда элементы не помещаются они перескакивают вниз
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}


https://doka.guide/css/flexbox-guide/?ysclid=lwap3q376z436752310
